# Android Java NullPointerException on openInputStream from Camera Intent data

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, camera

When I try to get the result from the camera I keep getting a "NullPointerException: uri" at the line:

```
InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

from the code:

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        try {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            pic.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            bitmapPic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
```

Being pic an ImageViewer and the image is successfully placed in the ImageViewer I can't seem to find the reason as to why this is not working.

Also here's the code for the Intent that starts the image capturer.

```
pic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

And the part of the code that I will use it on after this is working, or at least trying to:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
    mStorageRef.child(animal.getPictureID()).putBytes(data);
```

Being the last line Firebase related.

Also bitmapPic is a Bitmap.

Edit 1: Tried a suggestion by adding global variable:

```
private FileProvider mImageUri;
```

then

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mImageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        }
```

But it says that putExtra combination doesn't exist. Not sure if that's what you meant.

Edit 2: Managed to get it working. As of now it only sends the Thumbnail but at least it's something here's how I did it:

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        try {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            pic.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            encodeBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```

where:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos;

 public void encodeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
}
```

And finally to send it to firebase I used this:

```
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
mStorageRef.child(animal.getPictureID()).putBytes(data);
```

Comment: `When I try to get the result from the camera ` The result you got already. You took the bitmap. A thumbnail of the image. But there is no uri as the camera app did not save the full image to file. You did not ask that app to do that. If you want a full image than invoke the camera intent with a putExtra() for Intent.EXTRA_STREAM.

Comment: @greenapps You mean use: intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri); ? Where mImageUri would be a global Uri?

Comment: Intent.EXTRA_STREAM. and the uri a FileProvider uri for the file where the image should be saved. There is no thumbnail then.

Comment: intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mImageUri); Where mImageUri is a FileProvider gives a "Cannot Resolve" error.

Comment: Please put your code in an extra code block in your post. `Where mImageUri is a FileProvider` You cannot put a FileProvider there where a FileProvider uri is expected. What are you doing?